# Как узнавать нажатие CheckBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу изменять цвет фона нажатиями CheckBox

И что-то не работает

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void CheckBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox CBR = checkBox3;
            CheckBox CBG = checkBox2;
            CheckBox CBB = checkBox1;
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            if (CBR.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (CBG.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            if (CBB.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            if (CBR.Checked && CBG.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (CBR.Checked && CBB.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            }
            if (CBR.Checked && CBG.Checked && CBB.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            if (CBG.Checked && CBB.Checked)
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                form1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
        this.checkBox2.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
        this.checkBox3.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
    }

    private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox CBR = checkBox3;
        CheckBox CBG = checkBox2;
        CheckBox CBB = checkBox1;

        if (CBR.Checked && CBG.Checked && CBB.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else if (CBR.Checked && CBG.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (CBR.Checked && CBB.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Purple;
        }
        else if (CBG.Checked && CBB.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
        }
        else if (CBR.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (CBG.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (CBB.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно сделать event handler на каждый CheckBox, общий для всех. Не надо создавать новый объект `Form`, работайте с `this`. И наконец, я расположил проверки по убыванию количества отмеченных `CheckBox`, чтобы каждое условие выполнялось один раз.

Comment: Имя "CheckBox_CheckedChanged" не существует в текущем контексте.